# How would I search "Location" based on primary keys such as BAccountID and LocationID through Web Service API?

Tags: c#, acumatica

As I indicated in my another question at [Is there any way to get BAccountID when searching Business Account, or update Business Account based on those primary keys through Web Service API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085459/is-there-any-way-to-get-baccountid-when-searching-business-account-or-update-bu), I was trying to get Primary Key value such as `BAccountID` from `BAccount` table, which I did - thanks to @Stan 's help - now I need to search "Location" based on `BAccountID` and `LocationID`, which are two primary keys in "Location" table; however, I couldn't get it work.

Can somebody give me a help to show me how to get it work? @Stan, would you please help me again?

Thanks!

As @ryanyuyu suggested, the following is what I tried but didn't work:

```
CR303010Content CR303010 = context.CR303010GetSchema();
context.CR303010Clear();

List<Command> cmds = new List<Command>();
cmds.Add(CR303010.LocationSummary.ServiceCommands.EveryLocationID);

cmds.Add(CR303010.LocationSummary.LocationID);
cmds.Add(CR303010.LocationSummary.LocationName);

List<Filter> filters = new List<Filter>();

filters.Add(new Filter()
{             
   Field = NewA4Field(CR303010.LocationSummary.BusinessAccount.ObjectName, "BAccountID"), 
   Value = "8145",
   Condition = FilterCondition.Equals,
   Operator = FilterOperator.And
});
filters.Add(new Filter()
{
  Field = NewA4Field(CR303010.LocationSummary.LocationID.ObjectName, "LocationID"),
  Condition = FilterCondition.Equals,
  Value = "9488",
});
 var CR303010Export = context.CR303010Export(cmds.ToArray(), filters.ToArray(), 0, false, false);
```

---

```
public static apisalesorder.Field NewA4Field(string objName, string fldName)
{
        apisalesorder.Field nv = new apisalesorder.Field();
        nv.ObjectName = objName;
        nv.FieldName = fldName.TrimEnd();
        return nv;
}
```

Comment: Even though you provide a link to another question, we still need the specifics for this question including why it is not working.

Comment: @ryanyuyu, sorry for the confusion - I guess I shouldn't say "I couldn't get it work" instead, I should say I don't know how to search Location based on primary keys (BAccountID and LocationID). Basically I don't know how to do it since neither of BAccountID or LocationID is available in the fields. Having said that, I did try something similar to what Stan showed in another question I provided a link to but no matter how I tried just didn't work. That is why I asked somebody to help with the best way to do this. I will add those code to my questions anyway.

Comment: Why do you need to work with BAccountID and LocationID instead of using AcctCD and LocationCD (the value that is visible to users, and that is also unique) ?

Comment: @Gabriel, is LocationCD unique in database? I only see BAccountID and LocationID are primary keys...that is the reason why I want to use them instead of LocationCD - I thought LocationCD were not unique. Can you please confirm it? Thanks.

Comment: LocationCD is unique for a given business account. So you would retrieve the location by specifying the customer code and location code (two keys).

Comment: Thanks, Gabriel! I'm going to use Customer code and Location code as you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Gabriel suggested, I'm going to use Customer code and Location code to get Location info and if I do need to get Location data based on primary keys, I will use Generic Inquiry instead. Thanks for Gabriel's help!